# How to Display Corresponding Login Page for user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, apache, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have an application where there are three users, all three having separate login URLs.

```
Eg: https://user1.mydomain.com
https://user2.mydomain.com &
https://user3.mydomain.com
```

I have created the above A and CNAME records in GoDaddy to point these to my AWS EC2 instance. And also created corresponding .conf entries in Apache config to enable all these sites.

Now, since all these routes are governed by Laravel routes, I am not sure what folder to put under the sites-enabled conf file to enable the correct login page to be displayed for each sub-domain. Currently I have it like this:

```
# Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex login.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain/public/
```

My approach is correct or I need to do changes elsewhere to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the login page based on you subdomains directly in your web.php Laravel route file.

For example:

```
<?php

Route::domain('user1.mydomain.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', 'YourAuthController@loginUser1')->name('loginUser1');
});  

Route::domain('user2.mydomain.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', 'YourAuthController@loginUser2')->name('loginUser2');
});  

Route::domain('user3.mydomain.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', 'YourAuthController@loginUser3')->name('loginUser3');
});
```

References: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Comment: Hi I tried this, but now getting 404 error when trying to access the route. My root folder in apache conf is pointed to the public directory. Is there any other change required to make the route load?

Comment: It's correct to point to the public folder, the index file should be index.php, not index.html. You can list your route with the command ```php artisan route:list```, do you see the routes with this command?